# Link libraries when compiling g++

Tags: compiling, linker, g++

I am trying to link some libraries my g++ code and I am getting the following error:

```
$ g++ -O myprob.o  -o myprob -Wl,-rpath $PATH/lib -L$PATH/lib -lprob7_cpp -lprob7
g++.exe: error: c:\mypath;c:\mypath\lib: Invalid argument
```

If I try and run this command without the `-Wl,-rpath $PATH/lib` part, which I think I should be able to do, then I get this error:

```
$ g++ -O myprob.o  -o myprob -L$PATH/lib -lprob7_cpp -lprob7
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lprob7_cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lprob
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have been tinkering with this for hours and can't seem to figure this out.

I have already compiled my `.cpp` files successfully with the following command:

```
$ g++ -O -I$PATH/include -c myProb.cpp -o myProb.o
```

How can I correct these errors?

Comment: g++ failed to find library `prob7_cpp` and `prob7`, namely `libprob7_cpp.a` and `libprob7.a` files in library search path set by `-L`.  Check your configuration and files you aleady built.

Comment: The `$PATH` is a variable in linux containing all paths to look for command binaries when calling them by name. You probably were trying to use the path to working directory `$PWD`?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use your `$PATH` variable in the compile line options !!!

Try to use this command line in place:

```
$ g++ -O myprob.o  -o myprob -Wl,-rpath ./lib -L./lib -lprob7_cpp -lprob7
```